# How to get page view count on wagtail/django?

Tags: django, wagtail

I am planning to create a page within a blog website where it arranges and displays the all blog posts based on page view count. Not sure how to pull it off.

**models.py**

```
class BlogPost(Page):
    date = models.DateField(verbose_name="Post date")
    categories = ParentalManyToManyField("blog.BlogCategory", blank=True)
    tags = ClusterTaggableManager(through="blog.BlogPageTag", blank=True)
    body = RichTextField(blank=False)

    main_image = models.ForeignKey(
        'wagtailimages.Image', 
        null=True,
        blank=False,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL, 
        related_name='+')

    def get_context(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context(request, *args, **kwargs)
        blogposts = self.get_siblings().live().public().order_by('-first_published_at')
        context['blogposts'] = blogposts
        return context

    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
        FieldPanel('date'),
        FieldPanel('categories', widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple),
        FieldPanel('tags'),
        ImageChooserPanel('main_image'),
        FieldPanel('body', classname="full"),
    ]
```

Answer (score 5):

As mentioned in another answer, you can add `view_count` field to your model. Then you can leverage Wagtail's hooks to increment the value in database.

New field in the model:

```
class BlogPage(Page):
    view_count = models.PositiveBigIntegerField(default=0, db_index=True)
```

Register the `before_serve_page` hook:

```
@hooks.register("before_serve_page")
def increment_view_count(page, request, serve_args, serve_kwargs):
    if page.specific_class == BlogPost:
        BlogPost.objects.filter(pk=page.pk).update(view_count=F('view_count') + 1)
```

In this approach database takes responsibility to correctly increment `view_count` so you don't have to worry about locking and incrementing the value yourself.

Answer (score 4):

If you wanted to count views in a slightly more featured way you could use the `django-hitcount` package.

Your `wagtail_hooks.py` file would then become:

```py
from hitcount.models import HitCount
from hitcount.views import HitCountMixin

from wagtail.core import hooks

from home.models import BlogPage

@hooks.register("before_serve_page")
def increment_view_count(page, request, serve_args, serve_kwargs):
    if page.specific_class == BlogPage:
        hit_count = HitCount.objects.get_for_object(page)
        hit_count_response = HitCountMixin.hit_count(request, hit_count)
```

You need to add `HitCountMixin` to your `Page` definition, i.e.

```py
from hitcount.models import HitCountMixin

class BlogPage(Page, HitCountMixin):
```

This allows you to count hits but avoid duplication from the same IP, to reset hits with a management command, and to set the 'active' period for a page.

You will also need to `pip install django-hitcount` and add it to your `INSTALLED_APPS` in `settings.py`.

Comment: I've finally found what I was looking for! I was starting to get frustrated in a suspicion that I should not have tried out Wagtail in the first place and just gone the regular Django way, as I didn't see how to implement something like this without being able to directly affect views the Django way in Wagtail. I couldn't also find anything on counting hits in Wagtail docs.

Answer (score 2):

As a naive solution, you could add a field `view_count` to your `BlogPage` model, this would be a `IntegerField`.

You will need a way to update this value every time the page is served, you can add some logic to the `get_context` method you have already used. However, the [`serve`](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/reference/pages/model_recipes.html#overriding-the-serve-method) method would be more appropriate, be sure to check that the serve is not being called as a preview by checking `request.is_preview`.

In regards to querying (ordering by this `view_count`), this can be done by updating your query.

```
blogposts = self.get_siblings().live().public().order_by('-view_count')
```

You can make this new field visible, but not easily editable (client side validation only) by adding it via a [`FieldPanel` with a custom `widget`](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/reference/pages/panels.html#fieldpanel). Using the Wagtail [`settings_panels`](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/topics/pages.html#editor-panels) this can be made available in the non content panel.

### Example Model

**`models.py`**

```py
from django.db import models
from django import forms

from wagtail.core.models import Page


class BlogPage(Page):
    # ... other fields

    view_count = models.IntegerField(blank=False, default=0)

    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
        # ... existing content panels
    ]

    settings_panels = Page.settings_panels + [
        FieldPanel(
            'view_count',
            #  show the view count in the settings tab but do not allow it to be edited
            #  note: can be easily edited by savvy users, but only if they can also access admin
            widget=forms.NumberInput(attrs={'disabled': 'disabled', 'readonly': 'readonly'})
        )
    ]
```

Please note: this implementation does not take into consideration any other case where `serve` may be called but does not mean 'a unique user saw my blog post'. You may want to investigate a proper Django analytics solution or some kind of integration with client side analytics such as Google Analytics or Heap.