# serve() is called twice everytime I reload a blog page in wagtail

Tags: python, django, wagtail

I am using wagtail to build a blog website. In order to count the visits of each blog, I override the get_context() and serve() to set cookie. The codes are as follows:

```
    def get_context(self, request):

        authorname=self.author.get_fullname_or_username()
        data = count_visits(request, self)

        context = super().get_context(request)
        
        context['client_ip'] = data['client_ip']
        context['location'] = data['location']
        context['total_hits'] = data['total_hits']
        context['total_visitors'] =data['total_vistors']
        context['cookie'] = data['cookie']
        context['author']=authorname
        return context
    
    def serve(self, request):
        context = self.get_context(request)
        print(request.COOKIES)
        template = self.get_template(request)
        
        response = render(request, template, context)
        response.set_cookie(context['cookie'], 'true', max_age=3000)
        return response
```

And the function count_visits is as follows:

```
def count_visits(request, obj):       
    data={}
    ct = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(obj)
    key = "%s_%s_read" % (ct.model, obj.pk)
    if not request.COOKIES.get(key):      
        blog_visit_count, created =BlogVisitNumber.objects.get_or_create(content_type=ct, object_id=obj.pk)
        blog_visit_count.count += 1
        blog_visit_count.save()
```

The problem I met is that when I reload the blog page, serve() was loaded twice. The first time request was with cookie info. But the second time the cookie of the request was {}, which caused the count of visit does not work correctly.
I do not understand why serve() is called twice everytime I reload page.
After adding a print command in serve(), the log of reload blog page is as follows:

```
[19/Sep/2022 23:08:44] "GET /notifications/api/unread_list/?max=5 HTTP/1.1" 200 38
{'csrftoken': 'vAnNLAp8Fb9zPkUOSrHTFGB5Bp4W4aLu8mQWPklIhX1JpDTcKIceeId03jTKJpA3', 'sessionid': '9qdgjulitvosan1twtqe0h5bpfn4z3hg', 'bloglistingpage_7_read': 'true', 'blogdetailpage_6_read': 'true'}
[19/Sep/2022 23:08:44] "GET /blog-1/ HTTP/1.1" 200 27594
{}
[19/Sep/2022 23:08:45] "GET /blog-1/ HTTP/1.1" 200 23783
[19/Sep/2022 23:08:46] "GET /notifications/api/unread_list/?max=5 HTTP/1.1" 200 38
```

And the log of curl is:

```
[19/Sep/2022 23:12:24] "GET /notifications/api/unread_list/?max=5 HTTP/1.1" 200 38
{}
[19/Sep/2022 23:12:29] "GET /blog-1/ HTTP/1.1" 200 23783
```

Comment: Please try a single request with `curl` (or `wget`) and show us the logs.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I have edited the question to include the logs.

Comment: As an aside, your visitor counting has a race condition; you'll need to use `F()` to atomically update the count. See [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/expressions/#avoiding-race-conditions-using-f).

Comment: If the indentation is correct as shown, then `serve()` is a sub-function inside of `get_context()`, which is likely not what you intended.

Comment: From the logs you provided I do not see that serve() is being called twice, but rather that there are two different requests (`GET /notifications/api/unread_list/` and `GET /blog-1/`). If your goal is to count the visits, have a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67164044/7373966

Comment: @JohnGordon The incorrect indentation is caused by copy codes. The indentation is correct in my program.

Comment: @FlorinC. When reloading the page, there are 2 requests. You can see from the log there are 2 `GET /blog-1/` requests. The first is with correct COOKIE info and the second the request. COOKIE is {}. `GET /notifications/api/unread_list` has no relation with the reloading. It is sent every several seconds to refresh the notification. But I will study the answer you mentioned. Thank you.

Comment: @AKX Thank you for the help. I will study the F() you mentioned.

Comment: I have studied the suggestions. hitcount package seems to be able to solve the problem of counting visits to each blog. But it requires a modification to the frame. F() seems not to be helpful in my case, because I need to override serve() to set_cookies to judge whether to count the visit or not. But Wagtail will call serve() twice for 1 reloading page operation. Interesting thing is that the same logic works fine if I do not use wagtail and write the codes in the view of Django. Anyone can give me a hint why this happens?